# C# - Get XElement.Value in a custom datetime format

Tags: c#, xelement, iformatprovider

Here is my problem:

I have a `XElement` storing a `DateTime`, and I want to get the Value property returning the `DateTime` in a custom format.
I was wondering if there is a way to include a `IFormatProvider` in the `XElement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing things here. The `XElement` always stores its value as a string. To get a custom date format, you need to convert this string into a `DateTime` object first and then call `ToString` with the format you want to have.

Comment: And there is no way to add a datetime without call the ToString method to reach my goal? As the XElement.add method can receive an object, it migth have a way to do it.

Comment: @dcidral: No. It internally just converts the supplied object to a string. If the object is a `DateTime` it uses `XmlConvert.ToString(value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind);` for this conversion.

Comment: thanks for reply. I don't know why MS didn't think about it, now I'll need to format all the elements by myself.

Comment: That's not an oversight. It only makes sense, because XML can only store text. It can't store arbitrary objects.

Comment: Yeah but it should have a way to set the text format of the objects, it would be very helpful. And the XmlConvert could be an interface making the things more flexible to the programmer.

Comment: I don't agree. That `XElement.Add` accepts arbitrary `object`s instead of only `string`s is only for your convenience. If you don't agree with the default formatting, you can simply convert the object to a string of a format of your liking and pass that string to `XElement.Add`. You could even create an extension method if this is a common use case in your application.